# Soviet patent for a low pressure boiling washing machine?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machine-design

I once (in the 1980's) heard about a Soviet patent for a low pressure boiling washing machine, that washed the clothes (without detergents) by reducing the pressure and then basically boiling the clothes at e.g. 40 C or 60 C, instead of 100 C. The bubbles somehow removed the dirt. Anyone ever heard of this? What was the name of the invention? Patent number? Did it ever go into production anywhere?

Comment: So checked the patents?

Comment: a special  extra-cold-water washer?  Sounds like it was invented for the ad copy not for effectiveness.  "Soviet winters make for the best cleaning!"   Boiling water by lowering the pressure makes it cold fast.  See Lysenkoism